# Cassandra Declare and Working with Variables

Tags: variables, cassandra, cql, cql3, declare

I couldn't find any example/article about working with inline variables in cql.

Basically my structure is like this;

```
1 Keyspace(x)
2 Tables (a,b)
```

I have to select result from x.a to code first and then send them to x.b

As you can see i have to go CAS **2** times. But i can do it with single query.

any way to declare and work with inline variables?

thanks already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what client driver you are using, but any modern CQL driver should support [Bound Statements](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/developer/java-driver/2.0/java-driver/quick_start/qsSimpleClientBoundStatements_t.html), which is how you would paramaterize your queries.

You can't do a dependent query like that on two tables in a single round trip. The second one will have to be executed by your client code after you get the result from the first.

Comment: Missing parts from me: I'm using cassandraSharp v4 for C# in VS. Just checked the CQL Documentation and changed my structure. Everything works well from now on.

Thanks for your quick reply! :)